# Unable to get Python working

Tags: python, windows, installation

I am unable to get Python to run on my computer properly. Python - Idle 3.4.3 was working on my computer until I downloaded and installed 2.7.9 on my computer to run a script my friend created. Ever since then I haven't been able to get Python working. When I run the application, it opens up what appears to be cmd:

[image: Screenshot of command-line Python]

I want it to open IDLE instead so I can create a new file. It should look like this:

[image: Screenshot of working IDLE]

I have tried uninstalling both, cleaning the registry and such, and then reinstalling 3.4.3, but it keeps giving me the same results, knowing that it has been previously installed.

I have no idea what’s going on, but any help or comments are appreciated :)
If I am unable to get Python working I will probably resort to booting Linux on my computer and running IDLE/Python on that (not fun…).

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in those screenshots.

Comment: I don't know how to create new files and run them etc. in the black one it's just a shell

Comment: Just run `python filename.py`.

Comment: I <3 you KSFT! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's working right. Just pass the name of the file the program's in as an argument:

```
python file.py
```